# Sorting list of objects c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have list of clients:

```
Client o = new Client();
List<Client> listO = o.dtGetClients();
```

I want to sort the `listO` by `UserName`, but when I do it by *Linq*:

```
List<Client> SortedList = listO
  .OrderBy(X => X.UserName)
  .ToList();
```

I get a *different* instance of `List<Client>`. How can I do it *in-place* (i.e. I want `listO` been sorted, not `SortedList`)?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Is it not sorting correctly?

Comment: Sort  does not work remain such as what are they where

Comment: You mention that you have a list in a gridview in one of the below comments. Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged and telling the gridview that the List has been sorted?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a *misterious* one: "The list...". In case the lost fragment is "*should be sorted in-place*":

```
  Client o = new Client();

  var listO = o.dtGetClients();

  listO.Sort((Comparison<Client>) 
    ((left, right) => String.Compare(left.UserName, right.UserName)));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you man aged to infer that from his question. But judging from his reply to my question this is probably what he wanted.

Comment: i have list of objects in grid view i want to sorted in My event
but my problem "not error" 
the list remain not change :)

Comment: @Mohammed: right, you're creating a *new instance* of `List<Client>`  (i.e. `SortedList`) when you should sort the existing instance (i.e. `listO`); we call it *"sort in place"*.